# Can someone please explain why this gives an index out of range error?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why this is giving out this error, i've tried reformatting the code and checking if anything is wrong but I still cannot get a right answer

```
 n=int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
    m=[]
    for i in range(2*n-1):
        m.append([])
        m[i].append(1)
        for j in range (1,i):
            m[i].append(m[i-1][j-1]+m[i-1][j])
        if n != 0:
            m[i].append(1)
    pTr = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(i,n+1):
            row.enter code hereappend(m[j][i])
        pTr.append(row)
    print("The pascal matrix is as shown below")
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print("{0:6}".format(pTr[i][j]), end=" ")
        print()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code fails to run due to indentation errors, and it hangs waiting for input you haven't provided.  We also need the full error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print `n` rows of Pascal's triangle.
However, your output loop insists on finding `n` elements in every row of the triangle.  As soon as it hits the shorter rows, it crashes.

A simple `print` trace shows the error:

```
print("The pascal matrix is as shown below", pTr)
```

Output for n=4 (split into separate lines):

```
[
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [1, 4]
]
```

Your code crashes when you insist on printing 4 elements of a list that has only 3 elements.